# Angular form data structure to web api

Tags: angular

if I want to send some form data to a web api, does it have to match the structure of it, I want to send to this example:

```
{
    "result": [
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP2355 Black and White",
    "u_address_floor": "1",
    "u_address_line_1": "15 Rue De Cambrai",
    "u_address_post_code": "75019"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP26789 All Colour",
    "u_address_floor": "2",
    "u_address_line_1": "14 London Road",
    "u_address_post_code": "78900"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP2678 Black and Yellow",
    "u_address_floor": "3",
    "u_address_line_1": "13 Champs Elyses",
    "u_address_post_code": "78987"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP7898 Black and white",
    "u_address_floor": "4",
    "u_address_line_1": "17 Rue De Cambrai",
    "u_address_post_code": "75019"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP2355 Black and white",
    "u_address_floor": "5",
    "u_address_line_1": "11 Rue De Cambrai",
    "u_address_post_code": "75019"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP2355 Black and white",
    "u_address_floor": "6",
    "u_address_line_1": "11 Rue De Cambrai",
    "u_address_post_code": "75019"
  },
  {
    "u_serial_number": "E745K100200",
    "u_product_name": "MP2355 Black and white",
    "u_address_floor": "7",
    "u_address_line_1": "11 Rue De Cambrai",
    "u_address_post_code": "75019"
  }
 ]
}
```

But my component is not sending anything yet, I just get bad request. Please not the above is the structure, however the fields are different in my code:

**component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Request } from '../../models/request.model'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppComponent } from '../../../app.component';
import { ServicenowService } from '../../services/servicenow.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, } from '@angular/common/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-service-request',
  templateUrl: './service-request.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-request.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceRequestComponent implements OnInit {


  public loading = false;

  private customer_id = 7; /// this.appComponent.customer_id;

  serviceForm;

  u_destination_country = [
    { value: 'Choose an option' },
    { value: 'United Kingdom', },
    { value: 'United States of America', },
    { value: 'Russia', },
    { value: 'Moscow', },
    { value: 'Africa', },
  ];

  users = [
    { id: 'Select an option', },
    { id: '1', },
    { id: '2', },
    { id: '3', },
  ];

  devices = [
    { id: 'Select an option', },
    { id: '1', },
    { id: '2', },
    { id: '3', },
  ];

  constructor(private service: ServicenowService,
    private appComponent: AppComponent,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient

  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceForm = new FormGroup({
      customer_id: new FormControl(this.customer_id),
      //u_caller_id: new FormControl(this.users[0], Validators.required),
      siebel_id: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      u_destination_country: new FormControl(this.u_destination_country[0], Validators.required),
      u_phone_number: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      //u_serial_number: new FormControl(this.devices[0], Validators.required),
      short_description: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.maxLength(80)
      ])),
      u_message_description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.http.post("/api/incident", 
       this.serviceForm.value,
       {
          headers : new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type","application/json")
       }
    ).subscribe((response : any)=>{
        console.log(response);//On success response
        this.router.navigate(['/incident/confirmation']);
    },(errorResponse : any)=>{
        console.log(errorResponse);//On unsuccessful response
    });
 }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicenowService {

  serviceApiUrl: string = '/api/incident';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,

  ) { }

  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.serviceApiUrl)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  getIncidents(customerId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.serviceApiUrl + "?customer_id=" + customerId)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
/*
  postIncidents(customerId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.serviceApiUrl + "?customer_id=" + customerId, null)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
*/

postIncidents(params = {}): Observable<any> { 
  return this.http.post<any>(this.serviceApiUrl, params)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log(error.error.message)

    } else {
      console.log(error.status)
    }
    return throwError(
      console.log('Something is wrong!'));
  };

}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am trying to resolve this.

Comment: You should look at the details of the error that you are getting.

Comment: Why are you posting directly in the Component while you have that method in the Service?

Comment: if it is a bad request check in the API for the expected body

Answer (score 0):

Bad request means you are posting some data what is not matching with the data the server is looking for. If the data is as in your example you should send something similar
example:

```
let dataToSend= {
   "u_serial_number": this.serviceForm.value.u_serial_number,
   "u_product_name": this.serviceForm.value.u_product_name,
   "u_address_floor": this.serviceForm.value.u_address_floor,
   "u_address_line_1": this.serviceForm.value.u_address_line_1,
   "u_address_post_code": this.serviceForm.value.u_address_post_code
},
```

also if the server for example looking for an integer you need to convert it to integer.

but there could be other reasons as well...
hope this helps